# Variables fail comparison but display values are the same

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, which cycles through some cells and populates them with values. It works fine, except now I'm trying to keep track of the total value of all the populated cells in a row. After a row is populated, I want to know if the sum of the populated cells is not equal to the value stored in Column C in the current row (a.value).

When I do the If/Then comparing a.value to oAllocated, I get a couple of results I don't expect and the MsgBox appears to be displaying the same values, even though the MsgBox is being displayed because Excel says they aren't.

Even more confusing is that if I create a formula in a cell on the worksheet which sums the entries in the row and compares it to the a.value column, they match!!

```
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim oAllocated As Single


For Each a In wsSheet.Range("C3:C17").Cells
    If (IsEmpty(a) = False) Then
        oAllocated = 0
        For Each b In wsSheet.Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 4), Cells(Selection.Row, 17))
            If IsEmpty(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(b.Row, 1), Sheets("Allowable Activities").Range("A1:Q17"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(1, b.Column), Sheets("Allowable Activities").Range("A1:Q1"), 0), False)) = True Then
                If b.Value + (a.Value * Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(oSheetName, Sheets("Funder Salary Allocation").Range("B1:Q13"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(1, b.Column), Sheets("Funder Salary Allocation").Range("B1:Q1"), 0), False)) > 0 Then
                    b.Offset(0, 24).Value = b.Value + (a.Value * Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(oSheetName, Sheets("Funder Salary Allocation").Range("B1:Q13"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(1, b.Column), Sheets("Funder Salary Allocation").Range("B1:Q1"), 0), False))
                    oAllocated = oAllocated + CSng((b.Value + (a.Value * Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(oSheetName, Sheets("Funder Salary Allocation").Range("B1:Q13"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(1, b.Column), Sheets("Funder Salary Allocation").Range("B1:Q1"), 0), False))))
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If a.Value <> oAllocated Then
            MsgBox ("Allocated: " & CSng(a.Value) & " - Dispersed: " & oAllocated)
        End If
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next
```

Comment: Try to use the debugger, and watch the real values of `a.Value` and `oAllocated`. Maybe the type does not match. Also you can try to use `Value2` instead of `Value`. 

And why do you cast `a.Value` as a `Single` in the `MsgBox` and not in your condition?

Comment: If ZwoRmi's suggestion doesn't fix it, type following in immediate window: `? TypeName(a.Value)` and `? a.Value <> oAllocated` and show us the results.

Comment: It's probably a floating point error. Try rounding: `If Round(a.Value, 5) <> Round(oAllocated, 5) Then`

Comment: Insert a Debug.Print just before the `If` statement: `Debug.Print CSng(a.Value2) & "=" & oAllocated` and see what you get.

Comment: It definitely sounds like you have a miss-match of variable types (something I have come across in the past). Try value2 as suggested by @ZwoRmi or make sure to Dim the variables to matching data types.

Comment: WOOHOO! I ended up going with .value2 combined with Round. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 0):

`For Each b In wsSheet.Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 4), Cells(Selection.Row, 17))`
I don't see any context for "Selection", so that's going to produce potentially unpredictable results.

Comment: This was part of a much larger block of code, the selection gets made in an area I didn't include here.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same issue today. As long as you are sure your cells do not have any additional spaces and are the same format (which often causes this problem) then use the Range() command. Apparently Excel does not handle long infinite decimals that well.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113